# Apache port 8012 in use but still error message port 80 in use?

Tags: apache, xampp

I changed the port to listen to 8012 since I got this error:

```
[Apache]    Problem detected!
[Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
[Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
[Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
[Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

When clicking on Start I only got the message:

```
Attempting to start Apache service...
```

and that stays forever but when touching Start again I get the previously mentioned error...I restarted Xampp but still the same error